# Create MySQL procedure to map search column to another column

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is there a way to create a procedure that when a database is queried if the query contains a reference to column A that the search query is remapped so that it'll point the reference from column A to column B?

Comment: Stored procedures don't modify other queries. You have to call them explicitly.

Comment: To add to what @Barmar said. It sounds like this is some you would have to implement in application logic.

Comment: Yeh I thought so, someone has "make bug" so was hoping that I could create some sort of work around while waiting for them to fix. Who renames table columns without properly checking it's impact!